# Remote PC, Office PC connecting to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm not sure how to ask this question so let me explain my situation...

I generally work remotely but travel into the office once or twice a week. When I'm working remotely I use VPN to gain access to everything that I would as if I were in the office. When I'm writing code at home I'll grab the latest version of code that I'm working on from TFS and use the local workspace on the home pc. However, when I'm at the office I have no way of accessing that code unless I check it in from the home PC and I'd rather not check in half written code. What is the best possible way to half both sets of code available on both PC's? I've read about remote workspaces but I'm not sure how to set anything like that up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest answer is to shelve your changes. That way they get stored on the server but don't get committed to the code base, you can then unshelve and carry on where you left off. Plus this means you'll be working with code on your local machine, negating any issues with the von connection, you can also share shelvesets with other members of your team

Comment: Thank you! I just tried this by shelving some test code from my Home PC then using RDP, connecting to my office PC and I was able to grab the shelveset! This will make things a lot easier and more organized!